How to Link Two Company APIs Using an API Gateway for Secure Data Communication
I have two APIs for two different companies. The requirement is to create a link between them via an API gateway. For example, if the first company needs data from the second company's databases, the first company contacts the API gateway. The API gateway then sends the request to the API of the other company, ensuring security and authentication, retrieves the data, and vice versa. The tasks include not only retrieving data but also modifying, deleting, and adding data.
I have no issues with integrating the APIs with the databases; my main challenge is establishing communication between these APIs.
What I've Tried

I have set up KrakenD with Docker.
I configured basic routes between the APIs.
I attempted to implement authentication using KrakenD Designer.

What I expected:
I expected the API gateway to successfully route the requests between the two company APIs, ensuring secure communication and proper handling of data retrieval, modification, deletion, and addition.
The Issue
The main challenge I'm facing is establishing effective communication between the APIs. While I have no issues integrating the APIs with their respective databases, I'm struggling with configuring the gateway to handle security, authentication, and other policies effectively.
My Questions

Is an API gateway the best solution for this, or are there better alternatives?

Is KrakenD the best open-source option for this, and can it be run on my server without any external intervention?

What do I need to know to accomplish this?

Any additional information or resources would be greatly appreciated.


I am a beginner in this field and searching for free open-source solutions, not AWS or other paid services. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
